# I am getting an error angular property does not exist on type 'appcomponent'

Tags: html, css, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxvxd.png)Error

HTML COMPONENT

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp(inputTitle.value)"[value]="title"#inputTitle>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular';
}
onKeyUp(newTitle:string)
{
  this.title=newTitle;
}
```

I want to get data from a input text and use it to change it simultaneously.

Comment: Place the `onKeyUp` method in the `AppComponent` class.

Comment: @YongShun Can u be a little specific i am new to angular i didnt get what you were trying to tell

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onKeyUp` method should be placed inside the `AppComponent` class.

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Angular';

    onKeyUp(newTitle: string) {
        this.title = newTitle;
    }
}
```